# Setting custom font into lottie android

Tags: android, lottie

Lets say that I want to use this animation

https://lottiefiles.com/70883-animation-fade-in-fade-out

but change the font to custom view from my project.

[image]

Above screenshot is my fonts folder. But when I run the application, it gives error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/Arial.ttf
        at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:965)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.manager.FontAssetManager.getFontFamily(FontAssetManager.java:87)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.manager.FontAssetManager.getTypeface(FontAssetManager.java:61)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.getTypeface(LottieDrawable.java:1094)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.TextLayer.drawTextWithFont(TextLayer.java:238)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.TextLayer.drawLayer(TextLayer.java:161)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.BaseLayer.draw(BaseLayer.java:239)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.CompositionLayer.drawLayer(CompositionLayer.java:120)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.model.layer.BaseLayer.draw(BaseLayer.java:239)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.drawWithOriginalAspectRatio(LottieDrawable.java:1247)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.drawInternal(LottieDrawable.java:393)
        at com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable.draw(LottieDrawable.java:383)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1436)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22350)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21217)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22081)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4516)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4277)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:806)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21226)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:559)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:565)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:642)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4101)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3828)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
2022-08-31 15:03:59.029 11213-11213/com.reeplayer.android.dev E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

So here is the question, what is correct way to set custom font into lottie json file

Comment: Does it work when you use one of the other fonts, like `CocoSharp-Bold.ttf`?

Comment: @pykereaper no, none of them is working

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```kotlin
lottieAnimationView.setFontAssetDelegate(object : FontAssetDelegate() {
   override fun fetchFont(fontFamily: String): Typeface {
      return Typeface.createFromAsset(
         context.assets,
         "fonts/avertastd_regular.otf"
      )
   }
})
```

Also make sure that the name of your font is valid (lower case without space).

Comment: It works some lottie jsons. I think my other lottie file is not well defined